# How do I get these images centered on the page?

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I'm making an under construction page, consisting of a background image, and two images I made in Photoshop. They're saying something to the effect of "We're under construction" and "Product of Quinncuatro Productions". Everything shows up on the page perfectly right now, but the images really seem to like hugging to the left side of the page. This is what I've got right now. My most simple idea is in the style tags right now. My first and second ideas are in the header comments. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Think Klinck</title>
<style>
body{
background-image:url('metalBackground.jpg');
}
img{
margin-left:auto;
margin-top:auto;
}

/*This was the first idea that I had:
.UnderConstruction{
align:center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-top:auto;
}
.Q4Productions{
align:center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-top:auto;

And this was my second:
div.center{
margin-left:auto;
margin-top:auto;
}
*/
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="UnderConstruction" class="center">
<img src="UnderConstruction.gif" alt="ThinKlinch.com is regretfully under construction.">
</div>

<div id="Q4Productions" class="center">
<img src="Q4Productions.gif" alt="A product of Quinncuatro Productions.">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#UnderConstruction,#Q4Productions{
    text-align:center;
}​
```

Or

```
.center{
    text-align:center;
}​
```

This will center your images within the divs.

Comment: Aaaaand I feel dumb. Many thanks, stranger. I'll post your answer as accepted in 11 minutes when it allows me.